# Keeping consitent android styling

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

In my android application I have both programmatically generated buttons and buttons designed in a layout file.

My question is what is the best way to ensure that my programmatically generated buttons match the ones that are in my layout file?

Main Method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    Button subButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());

    subButton.setText("-");
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    subButton.setLayoutParams(lp2);

    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    container.addView(subButton);

}
```

Layout File:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example both buttons appear to be different.

Edit:

The difference between the two buttons are the height and width. I've tried to minimize the difference in parameters by making the button simple.

Edit 2:

[Picture of the XML button compared to the Generated button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjYOX.png)

Comment: Your image leads me to believe @ianhanniballake's answer is correct. Try `AppCompatButton subButton = new AppCompatButton(this);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for this problem.

Implementing a factory method is as simple as defining a method that constructs your object, and adds the required fields before returning it to you. This cuts down on a lot of boiler plate code.

Also, you're using layout elements for a RelativeLayout, so I'm going to show you a method that receives a RelativeLayout as its container. If you really are using a LinearLayout (or something else!), we'll have to deviate from your layout parameters to achieve the same looks.

A suitable example:

```
public Button getNewStyledButton(String text) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(text);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return button;
}
```

Then, whenever we need a styled button, it's as simple as calling:

```
yourRelativeLayout.addView(getNewStyledButton("-")); //replace "-" with your desired text. You can also pass a `Runnable` as an argument for the button callback.
```

Let me know if this helps you, and if you need help with your LinearLayout as well.

Comment: Thanks, This appears to be the best way to method to generate buttons. This combined with @joshgoldeneagle suggestion of using a button_style.xml. I'll create a new question about why the generated button and the layout button appear different.

Comment: Try ianhanniballake's suggestion, and wrap it in the factory method I've provided and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html), you'll want to use [AppCompatButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html) instead of `Button`. As explained in the [Support Library 22.1 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), the standard widgets are replaced with their AppCompat equivalents automatically for you when you define them in XML to ensure consistent styling across all API levels, but for programmatic usage you must manually ensure you use the AppCompat versions.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what was causing the difference between the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use the activity context instead:

```
Button subButton = new Button(this); // not getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: That doesn't make the two buttons identical.

Comment: @user3610520 What else is different about them? If you have any attributes on the button in XML, you will have to make equivalent modifications in your java code. Update your question to be more specific about what's different, but in any case you need to use an Activity context instead of an Application context.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button_style.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
<shape>
<gradient android:startColor="#449def" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:angle="270" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699" /> <corners android:radius="4dp" />
<padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp"
android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Then apply this style programmatically to your buttons:

```
 Button mybutton = new Button(this);
    mybutton.setText("Test Example");
    mybuttonsetId(R.string.myButton);
    myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.buttonstyle);
```

For buttons created in XML directly be sure to also reference the same style:

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/buttonstyle"
        />
```